# Include pdf file produced no output?

Tags: include

This is my Latex source

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf {test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should work fine if test.pdf exists. Can you show your log-file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! And do you get error messages in your log file? Please add the **first** error message to your question!

Comment: Log file is empty.

Comment: Again
log file is empty
I work with Winedt 10 ver 10.1
Consol Latex Exit Code=3228369022

Comment: I notice a space between the includepdf command and the file, perhaps that is the problem? Instead of \includepdf   {test} try removing the space ... change to \includepdf{test}.